# Satchmo: What does this error mean and how is it fixed?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

Ubuntu 13.04 - Python 2.7.4 - Django 1.4.5 - Satchmo_Store 0.9.3

When I run Satchmo's second installation test, it shows me the following two errors which appear to me to be the same error. Either way, I do not understand enough to know what it is trying to tell me or how to go about fixing it--

```
root@10:/home/ubuntu/src/satchmo/scripts/store# python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
FAIL: test_sitemap_index_with_https_request (django.contrib.sitemaps.tests.https.HTTPSDetectionSitemapTests)
A sitemap index requested in HTTPS is rendered with HTTPS links
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/tests/https.py", line 40, in test_sitemap_index_with_https_request
    """ % self.base_url.replace('http://', 'https://'))
AssertionError: '' != '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">\n<sitemap><loc>https://example.com/simple/sitemap-simple.xml</loc></sitemap>\n</sitemapindex>\n'

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 646 tests in 400.243s

FAILED (failures=2, skipped=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
root@10:/home/ubuntu/src/satchmo/scripts/store#
```

I greatly appreciate your kind help, insight, and thoughts! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it tells you that emty string does not equal this one: ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n\nhttps://example.com/simple/sitemap-simple.xml\n\n

most probably your environment is not completely setup or  there's a bug in the test